# How to use MQ-2 module?

Tags: how-does-it-work, smoke-sensor

I am totally new to hardware.

Recently I bought this MQ-2 module, but I couldn't figure how to get it to work, the on the ship worked but where is the output? I mean the place where I place the voltmeter?

This is a picture of it:

[image]

It has 5 connections (+5v, GND, NO, COM, NC ).

Comment: It's worth posting a datasheet or a link to product information for that particular module. Guessing from the connections it only offers a relay output presumably when a pre-set limit is exceeded, although if you want a voltage output they'll be a pin somewhere on the board you can connect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Peter says in a comment, there's a relay on that board. The output connections include COM, NO and NC connections that are usable as follows ...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzqGdQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### 1

So set your multimeter to resistance (ohms) and connect it from COM to NC. When there is enough gas to trigger the relay the resistance will increase from 0 to infinity (or at least to "out of range" - some multimeters show that as -1)

You could use the COM and NO connections to switch on a large and loud siren and/or strobe-light.

### 2

The board also contains an indicator LED. You can connect a voltmeter across the resistor next to it. When the LED is turned on the voltage across the resistor will rise from 0 to perhaps a few volts.

### 3

The board has an LM358 op-amp, I guess this is processing the [MQ-2](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/images/3/3f/MQ-2.pdf) output signal, it might be interesting to put a voltmeter on it's output. See [LM358 data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf) for pinout

Comment: @user2514409: If you find the answer useful, consider upvoting it and/or accepting it using the icons to the left of the top of the answer.

Comment: i accepted it put i cant up vote until i get 15 reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

VCC to 5V+ and GRD on negative, that's all you need to do to run this module. On the relay you, you can use it as normally open or normally close, use it as how you would use a switch on a basic circuit like to turn on an AC lightbulb whenever it detects gas. The other pin which are the analog 0 A0 and Digital output DO. You have to get  micro controller to use those pins

Answer (score 0):

Yes the board contains an LM358 op amp to amplify the signal output from the heater element of the MQ2 sensor, this way when it is exposed to LPG/CO2 gases,

The output coming out from the sensor also varies, and LM358 op amp is configured as a comparator, thus it drives the relay directly or using a BJT.

Note:The heater element which can  be seen with steel mesh, does not rapidly varies while exposed to LPG, it takes some time to change in its output signal.